# Un-masked Copper Boundary across RF section

Tags: pcb, rf, via

I have seen so many PCB which has an un-masked (without solder mask), copper boundary across RF sections. The boundary has `via-stitching` and there are also few openings in the boundary. Can someone explain their purpose? Please have a look at the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant Via Stitching.

In RF application, you have a lot of current flows happening that behave quite differently than in non-RF application, and can take some really weird ways.

This is to reduce this effect.

The via stitching is there to reduce high frequency current flow going though the internal layers, don't forget a PCB is a dielectric, but still conduct somewhat electricity, or charges, especially in high frequency application.

The traces are uncovered for the same reason, avoiding having current flow flowing above the solder mask and messing with the rest of the circuit.

Probably on top of these ring, a metallic housing might be soldered, acting as a Faraday cage and avoiding having EMI being emited by the circuit.

Like this:
[image: cage]

---

This doesn't apply to your question, but it is an interesting addition:

These types of uncovered rings are also sometimes used in acquisition when the signal carries nA level currents.

Called Guard trace, they usually feed a follower op-amp, and the ring is placed around the signal trace and connected to the output of the op-amp, bringing the ring to the same voltage as the trace and thus avoiding leakage current. The cutout are for the same reason

[image: guard trace]

Comment: Does current flow in solder mask?

Comment: You don't want solder to flow in solder mask. But electrons will take all possible paths, including thru solder mask at 1 or 3 or 20,000 electrons per second.

Comment: @abhiarora yes it does, very tiny amount though and also depends of the frequency. Current flows in any surface, liquid, gas, just some are better than the other at conducting or resisting current flow.

Answer (score 0):

In my openion, the unmasked guard trace  with vias ( spaced at 1/10th of least wavelength (10th harmonic roughly)) connecting to gnd has solder mask opening to create impedance mismatch on the top copper place so that the RF induced fields will bounce back at the unmasked portion of the copper; solder mask coating with finite dielectric constant has impact on impedance). The vias will take care of reflecting the EM fields inside the PCB acting like faraday cage.

furthermore, the unmasked regions can also be used as solder pads for soldering mechanical shielding enclosure to form volumetric shielding( mechanical enclosure + via fence + gnd plane).